# Can the iOS simulator remember to use Retina iPhone, and non-Retina iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, retina-display

This is probably a niche issue, and more of a niggle really, but:

Can I have Xcode build to the iPhone Retina simulator, and the iPad non-Retina simulator, automatically?

Even with a 27" iMac, the Retina iPad simulator is pretty unwieldy for quick testing, but I like to do all of my iPhone testing in Retina resolution. I'm finding myself constantly building to iPad, forgetting I left iPhone Retina on, and having it build to iPad in Retina resolution, then having to  switch, kill, and rebuild to avoid it taking over my entire display.

Minor frustration, anything that can be done about it? I do have keyboard shortcuts set up to each of the five device types (Pad, Pad Retina, Phone, Phone Retina 3.5, Phone Retina 4), but even when using those, I still need to re-build after changing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it through your scheme.

Click on your scheme > Edit Scheme... > In the menu on the left select 'Run [AppName].app' > Click the 'Options' tab > Change the 'iPad Simulator Display' and 'iPhone Simulator Display' dropdowns.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @JDx Fantastic, had no idea that was tucked away in there! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's possible by changing scheme options in your project settings.

This question was once asked on SO. You can find a solution here: [iOS simulator -- swap from retina iPhone to non-retina iPad in a single step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897963/ios-simulator-swap-from-retina-iphone-to-non-retina-ipad-in-a-single-step)